# How to invoke addChangeHandler of listbox on setting its index?

Tags: java, gwt, listbox

In listbox we have a onChangeHandler method , which is invoked when user select another index.
While creating a listbox , I am setting its index manually and after setting it to a particular point , i want to perform some operations on the basis of the item selected. So for that, i want to invoke addChangeHandler method at the time of filling of listbox only. Is it possible in any way?

```
   listBox = new ListBox();
   listBox.addItem("A");
   listBox.addItem("B");
   listBox.addItem("C");
   listBox.setSelectedIndex(2);
   listBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
   public void onChange(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
   SelectElement selectElement = listBox.getElement().cast();
   selectElement.getOptions().getItem(0).setDisabled(true);
   }
   });
```

Here, on setting index to 2 , i want to invoke addChangeHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
listBox.setSelectedIndex(2);
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createChangeEvent(), listBox);
```

Make sure you call the fireNativeEvent after a selection is set!